# How to delete an overwrite from a user in a channel (Discord.js V12)

Tags: discord.js

I tried lots of differents ways but didn't worked, I know it requieres

- Channel
- Id
- And the method that is .delete()
  Using permissionOverwrites

Couldn't get the correct order to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
channel.permissionOverwrites.get('member ID').delete();
```